# How many one to one correspondences are there from $A=\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5\}$ to $B=\{B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,B_5\}$ such that...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got this problem:

Let $A=\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5\}$ and $B=\{B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,B_5\}$ be two sets.
How many one to one correspondences (one to one and onto functions) from $A$ to $B$ are there that satisfy the condition:

$\exists i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $ f(A_i)=B_i$

Can you generalize the result when $A$ and $B$ have $n$ elements?

I am stuck on this problem for at least $2\frac{1}{2}$ hours.

Thanks any hint/help.

Comment: How many functions from $A$ to $B$ do not have such an $i$? How many functions total from $A$ to 4B$?

Comment: The answer to the original question would have been $5^5-4^5$. This new question, requiring bijections, will have to use inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: As the set elements do not matter, are we not just talking about permutations with fixed points? Having cycles of length 1?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

> What is the number of bijective functions from $A$ to $B$ where $A$ and $B$ both have $5$ elements? What is is for $A, B$ containing $n$ elements?

Now for the actual problem

> How many ways are there to chose the specific $i$ for wich $f(A_i) = B_i$?

Given an $i$ we can see that the number of functions with this particular value is the same as the number of bijections
$$g: A\setminus\{A_i\} \to B\setminus \{B_i\}$$
Where $f(A_j) = \cases{B_i & $i=j$ \\ g(A_j) & else}$. Use the first result to obtain this number. Then use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to get the total number of functions with a "fixed point".

Comment: Oops. I forgot to mention that the functions must be bijective. I've edited the question.

Comment: No,this anser is wrong, because more than $1$ $i$ could exist fixed, and you are counting those twice.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews inclusion exclusion principle is needed to compile the results.

Comment: You could do it that way, or you could just write $5^5-4^5$. (For the problem as originally written.) The number of functions without a fixed point is $4^5$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not for bijections...

Comment: True, but your approach doesn't work for bijections, either.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It does, after a simple edit I overlooked the first time ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are $5!$ bijections in total. Those you *don't* want to count are exactly the [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), of which there are $\left[5!/e\right]$ where $[\cdot]$ is the nearest-integer function. So the result is
$$ \left[5!(1-e^{-1})\right] $$